# Lock all opportunities Based on User

Tags: opportunity

I created a checkbox field on User Table named **Can Unlock**. I have a requirement based on this field I have to lock all opportunities for any particular user. can some help?

Comment: what is OWD of Opportunity?

Comment: Public Read/Write

Comment: Have you looked into using a Validation Rule?  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126253/validation-rule-to-prevent-editing-record

Comment: That solution is depend upon System Admin Profile. My requirement is based on Specific User with a checkbox field.

Comment: @Sam The solution David Cheng linked - in Robin de Bondt's answer - can be adapted for any Profile or to use a Custom Permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Permission set with a name like 'Lock Opportunities'.
And whenever your 'Lock' field on a specific user is ticked. Using Apex add a user to that permission set [In which Opportunity object has read-only access].
And if 'Lock' is removed from the user. You can remove that user from the Permission set using apex.
All you need is a Combo of Trigger and Apex Class to drive this functionality.

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thanks for response. I created  a trigger and an associate class. Also created a permission Set. But don't know this is not working. I am attaching my code snippet.