# Validation Rule - deny edit on Opportunity based on Stage + another field

Tags: validation, cpq

Attempting to create a rule that doesn't allow users to change an Opportunity in CPQ to "Closed Won" (final stage) without inputting text into the Use_Case field. This is what I have so far:

```
AND(

ISPICKVAL (StageName, "Closed Won"),

ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Evaluation"),

ISBLANK(  Use_Case__c ))
```

It evaluates to true if I use the below (without Stage change), so the problem has to be in the 2nd argument. Thing is, syntax is correct, and according to SFDC documentation, this looks like it should work. Any thoughts?

```
ISPICKVAL (StageName, "Closed Won"),

ISBLANK(  Use_Case__c ))
```

Comment: If the requirements are to disallow users to move to Closed Won without filling out Use_Case__c, I'm not sure if you even need to be looking at the prior StageName. The only reason you would want to do that is if you were explicitly requiring users to populate the Use_Case__c field when changing the Opportunity Stage from Evaluation to Closed Won, but not when changing from any other stage to Closed Won.

Comment: @NathanW exactly. Sorry I should've been more explicit. Essentially, I don't want users to be able to move it to 'Closed Won' from our "Evaluation" Stage without filling-out the Use_Case__c text field.

Comment: does your validation rule (with priorvalue) work when testing manually editing an opportunity record's stage from evaluation to Closed Won (excluding the CPQ part)?

Comment: No, but the second rule does i.e. can't have a closed_won without a Use_Case__c value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation Rule to prevent editing record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126253/validation-rule-to-prevent-editing-record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your answer, I would stress that readability is very important when it comes to declarative tools. You can write it out in a much easier to understand way by following a couple rules

1. Be consistent with style choices. Either use `AND` and `OR` or use `&&` and `||`, don't mix both together. I'd advise using `AND()` and `OR()` as that's typically more "readable" as you never know the background of an admin where `&&` and `||` may not be as familiar.
2. Indent - when you start getting larger logic, it's helpful to indent to understand what criteria applies to what parenthesis without having to eyeball it. You won't see your indents when viewing the rule, but do when you "edit" it.

Taking your requirement, there's two scenarios that can be written in plain terms:

1. Don't let a user set the Opportunity to "Closed Won" if `Use_Case__c` is blank and the prior value was `2 - Evaluation`
2. Don't let a user set the Opportunity to "Closed Won" if `Use_Case__c` is blank and the prior value was `3 - Legal / Procurement`

[Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) describe what each do. In the above, you have two scenarios where *either can be true*. Within each scenario you have multiple things that *all have to be true*. This is where `OR(logical1, logical2...)` and `AND(logical1,logical2,...)` can be combined. If either of your `AND()` operators are true within the `OR()`, the validation rule will be true/fire.

```
OR(
    /* Scenario 1 */
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "2 - Evaluation"),
        ISBLANK( Use_Case__c ),
        ISPICKVAL (StageName, "Closed Won")
    ),
    /* Scenario 2 */
    AND(
       ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "3 - Legal / Procurement"),
       ISBLANK(Use_Case__c),
       ISPICKVAL (StageName, "Closed Won")
    )
)
```

Comment: Great call-outs. I'm a bit green to Validation rules and declarative programming, so I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here's what I did:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "2 - Evaluation")

&&

ISBLANK( Use_Case__c )

&&

ISPICKVAL (StageName, "Closed Won"))

||

AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "3 - Legal / Procurement")

&&

ISBLANK( Use_Case__c )

&&

ISPICKVAL (StageName, "Closed Won"))
```